# Применить box-shadow только для одной стороны

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно сделать скрытый текст, но с градиентом. 
Беру вот этот скрипт http://jsfiddle.net/yurik417/6FYqf/ добавляю в него класс:

```
.shadow{
  z-index:-1;
  box-shadow:inset 0px -40px 90px 4px #ccc;
}
```

Применяю его к:

```
<p class="pr2 shadow">
  текст  
</p>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы градиент был НАД кнопкой "полный текст", а когда текст разворачивается градиента не было?

Может есть плагин для скрытого текста, с опцией градиента?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, градиент требуется такого плана:

```css
.hide {
  position: relative;
}

.hide:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;  
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255, 1) 10%,  rgba(255,255,255, 0) 80%);
}
```

```html
<div class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam voluptas itaque earum aspernatur nemo amet nostrum reprehenderit est eum, asperiores voluptate, reiciendis eaque laboriosam aliquam! Doloremque culpa magni, voluptatum voluptas?</div>
```

Так как, в примере ссылка на `полный текст` находится на одном уровне с текстом, то думаю надо обернуть видимую часть текста в отдельный блок. Например так:

```
....
$el.html('<div class="hide">' + textVisible + '</div>').append($afterLength).append($elTextHidden);
...
```

и уже к этому блоку применять стили. Например те, что я указал выше.

Соответственно, чтобы при клике на `полный текст` убирался градиент воспользуемся [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) для смены класса и [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) для поиска нашего `div` относительно ссылки `полный текст`

```
....
$more.siblings('div').toggleClass('hide');
```

Итого, получим что-то такое: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FYqf/59/)**

Comment: Да, спасибо, то что нужно.

Comment: только в моем случае изначально скрывается весь текст, ему почему-то присваивается значение `display: none`, решил проблему указав в ручную в классе `display: block`